# Get the path of images under Newly Created Folder

Tags: c#

I have created one folder(Name - Images) under main project, I want to get the path of images under this Images folder, so how to get this path....
It is WinForm app

Path of Images folder - E:\FileCopy\FileCopy\Images

Comment: Are you intending to load the images as resources?  What sort of app is it? `WinForms`? `ASP.NET`?  `WPF`? `XNA`?

Comment: @Amol I believe you've created the `Images` folder in wrong place. You should put it in your `Debug` folder in your project. >> `yourProjectFolder\bin\debug\Images`

Comment: Yes but, I dont want to create folder in debug folder... Other than Images folder can I use resources by adding new images resource folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you create `Images` in `debug` folder, you could get your folder path this way:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\Images\"
```

Comment: Whilst a fine answer, do we know its a `WinForms` app?  It might be `ASP.NET`?  Will this code work under `ASP.NET`?

Comment: It gives path from c drive, but I dont want it. I want to get path of images folder under project path. like E/FileCopy/Images/img.jpg

Comment: @MickyDuncan Good point! I have a really low experiment in `ASP.NET`. I just assumed that it's a `Winform` app.

Comment: @Amol where did you create your images folder?

Comment: FileCopy is my solution name and Same is Project name under it, Images folder is created under project name.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

get project path with bin\Debug 
and

```
var binIndex=projectPath.IndexOf(@"bin\Debug");
```

get index of bin. so images path is

```
var path =string.Format("{0}Images",@projectPath.Substring(0, binIndex));
```

Comment: You should use [Path.Combine()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx) rather than use string manipulation to form file paths